# SQL where clause to check if all selected column value is in a subquery select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Does the select concept below can be translated into an sql select?

```
select S_ID from table1 where S_Type = TYPE and all S_ID in (select S_ID from table2)
```

The concept of this is like below:

item1, item2, and item3 should all be in (select ITEMS from table)

The select statement should only return a row/s if all S_ID is in (select S_ID from table2)

Comment: Can you share some data present in S_ID column?

Comment: This is not clear to me.  What happens if all `S_ID` are not contained in `table2`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - please see my updated question

Comment: @onhax . . . This makes no sense.  Why not just select `s_id` from the second table?  What are `item_1` etc?  They are not in the query.

Comment: I think we definitely need sample data for both tables and the expected output.  I can't decide if you want a simple inner join or if you want a complicated comparison based on an entire subset of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `S_ID`s all of whose *items* are in the second table, then use aggregation

```
select t1.S_ID
from table1 t1
where t1.S_Type = 'TYPE' and
      t1.item in (select t2.item from table2 t2)
group by S_ID
having count(distinct t1.item) = (select count(distinct t2.item) from table2 t2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to put comparision operator then all

```
select S_ID from table1 where S_ID = ALL (select S_ID from table2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Gonna test this and be back in a minute